# python3 how to find the largest prefix of a string of bytes that is a substring of another

Tags: python, string, algorithm, search

I need to find largest prefix (string of bytes starting from the beginning) of a bytes object s1 that is a substring of another bytes object s2 and return the start location in s2 and length. In this case s2 happens to be overlapping s1 as well.

The optimal result is the longest prefix that starts closest to the end of s2.

I have tried to implement this using bytes.rfind method as below.

Note: This is trying to find the largest prefix starting at index `index` in the bytes object  `src` that is present earlier in src within a maximum of `maxOffset` bytes before `index`. Therefore, s1 is `src[index:]` and s2 is `src[index-maxOffset:index+maxLength-1]`. `maxLength` is the maximum length of prefix that I am interested in searching for.

```
def crl(index, src, maxOffset, maxLength):
    """
    Returns starting position in source before index from where the max runlength is detected.
    """
    src_size = len(src)
    if index > src_size:
        return (-1, 0)
    if (index+maxLength) > src_size:
        maxLength = src_size - index
    startPos = max(0, index-maxOffset)
    endPos = index+maxLength-1
    l = maxLength

    while l>1:
        if src[index:index+l] in src[startPos:index+l-1]:
            p = src.rfind(src[index:index+l], startPos, index+l-1)
            return (p,l)
        l -= 1
    return (-1, 0)
```

I have also tried to hand-code this as below since the previous implementation was very slow

```
def ocrl(index, src, maxOffset, maxLength):
    """
    Returns starting position in source before index from where the max runlength is detected.
    """
    size = len(src)
    if index>=size:
        return (-1, 0)
    startPos = index - 1 # max(0, index-maxOffset)
    stopPos = max(0, index-maxOffset)
    runs = {}
    while(startPos >= stopPos):
        currRun = 0
        pos = startPos
        while src[pos] == src[index+currRun]:
            currRun += 1
            pos += 1
            if currRun == maxLength:
                return (startPos, maxLength) #found best possible run
            if (pos >= size) or ((index+currRun) >= size):
                break
        if (currRun > 0) and (currRun not in runs.keys()):
            runs[currRun] = startPos
        startPos -= 1

    if not runs:
        return (-1, 0)
    else:
        # Return the index from where the longest run was found
        return (runs[max(runs.keys())], max(runs.keys()))
```

While 2nd implementation is faster, it is still very slow and I believe inefficient. How can I make this more efficient and run faster ?

Comment: Does [`os.path.commonprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html) make your functions any faster?

Comment: does it matter to `os.path.commonprefix` if the strings are having byte-values outside the printable ascii range ? does it treat characters like '.' or '/' in a special way ?

Comment: I don't see anything [in the sources](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e3474ed80a5e/Lib/posixpath.py) that should cause you any trouble regarding these issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can use a modified Knuth-Morris-Pratt string searching agorithm that matches substrings as long as it can and reminds the longest match found.

I am not sure that there is a benefit work backwards over forward, as when you have found a match you need to continue the search for a longer one (except when you have matched the whole string).

Comment: The reason for backwards is the larger context of the probem - the goal being the detection of longest prefix that is closest to the start of s1. If the same prefix occurs twice in s2, the one occurring second will be the right answer.

Comment: @MadhurikoushikèKoushik: I know that. I don't think that it makes a real difference because in most cases you must continue the search anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Build [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) for the second string and search for the first string in that array, choosing the last index of the longest common prefix

Comment: Thanks @MBo. Will try it shortly. My rep is apparently too low to be able to +1 your answer.